# Warning in execution plan about using tempdb in a Sort node

Tags: sql, sql-server, tempdb

Checking my execution plan it shows a warning in a Top N Sort step

> Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1 and 4 spilled thread(s), Sort wrote 4609 pages to and read 4609 pages from tempdb with granted memory 107360KB and used memory 107360KB

Is this a bad thing and how should I tackle it?

The original query was

```
select a.* from TableA a where id in (
    select a.id from TableA a join TableAB ab on a.id = ab.aid join TableB b on ab.bid = b.id
    order by a.datetime desc offset 1000000 rows fetch next 10 rows only
)
```

In case you wonder, the above was meant to be a faster version of

```
select a.* from TableA a join TableAB ab on a.id = ab.aid join TableB b on ab.bid = b.id
order by a.datetime desc offset 1000000 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

but although it ran faster, it gave that warning message above.

Comment: @shawnt00 on the contrary, TableA has a clustered index on the datetime column

Comment: Spill to disk (caching data on disk) isn't great - it takes a lot longer than just sorting in memory, but happens with large sorts and may still be acceptable, depending on your case. If possible, I try to remove them. In your specific situation, note that the two queries are not the same: if a is linked to multiple b records, the top one only shows the a record once, but the bottom multiple times. Also, is table b actually needed? Can you just use ab? Finally, an index (clustered or nonclustered) on ab, columns a_id then b_id, should remove the sort anyway.

Comment: What is the use case for this anyway? If it is a pagination query then just don't let people navigate to page 100,000 with 10 results per page. Consider using keyset pagination instead.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, it's preferable using `EXISTS` over `IN` clause, this is assuming that you don't want duplicates from TableA as @seanb.
a possible rewriting to the query using nested `EXISTS` would look like

```
select a.* 
from TableA a 
where exists(
    select 1 
    from TableA a1
    where a1.id = a.Id
        and exists(
            select 1 
            from TableAB ab 
            where a1.id = ab.aid 
                and exists (
                    select 1
                    from TableB b 
                    where ab.bid = b.id
                )
            )
    order by a1.datetime desc offset 1000000 rows fetch next 10 rows only
)
```

The SORT is inevitable, but it should happen on fewer columns than using the ORDER inside the `IN` clause.
Even if you see the spill warning, you can check the number of pages is reduced, IMO, 4609 pages (~36MB) spill shouldn't make much difference, unless you are running this every few seconds.

Comment: There is no such "rule". `EXISTS` and `IN` get the same plan. (unlike `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` which have different semantics and plans)

Comment: Thanks, but funny though, using `EXISTS` does not return any result with the `OFFEST`. And it is not as fast as the `IN` although it does eliminate the warning as it uses a different plan.

Comment: To be clear the different plan isn't due to `EXISTS` vs `IN`. It will be because the various joins inside the `IN` also got turned to `EXISTS`. This could be written with the same nested `IN` and give the same plan